# How can we read files from storage container azure using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, azure

In aws, used to get the files from s3 like this

```
 s3 = boto3.client('s3')
 object = s3.get_object(Bucket='ringr-dev',Key=file_name)
 serializedObject = (object['Body'].read().decode('utf-8'))
 data = json.loads("[" + serializedObject.replace("}\n{", "},\n{") + "]")
 jsonStr = data[0]
```

In azure, trying to code but i am not able to read,

```
 from azure.storage.blob import BlobClient
 blob = BlobClient(account_url="https://abc.blob.core.windows.net",
              container_name="sourcemetadata",
              blob_name="1eea7b89-f114-4ca.json",
              credential="qBncEBNxfwkBw+7UcxFFDIWCLRISg11gLyYxnwOxd+jLoYl")
data = blob.download_blob()
```

Not able to read the data. Please guide!

Comment: you want to download or list the blobs inside the container?

Comment: @Sajeetharan We need to read the file from container and do further processing

Comment: @Sajeetharan  If i have the path abc/example/abc.png  How can i configure the folder inside the container in the python script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you have a chance to read the official [`documentation`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-quickstart-blobs-python#download-blobs)?

```
from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient
connection_string=''
blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient.from_connection_string(connection_string)
container_client = blob_service_client.get_container_client("<container name>")
blob_client = container_client.get_blob_client("<blob name>")
blob_client.download_blob().readall() # read blob content as string
```

Comment: How can we find the file with prefix "abc" from container